# Pythonのデフォルトバージョンを2.7.6から2.7.10に変更したい。

Tags: python, macos

Pythonのデフォルトバージョンを2.7.6から2.7.10に変更する方法について質問させていただきます。

Mac (OS 10.9.5 Mavericks) でPythonを使用しており、サイトからPython(2.7.6)を、Macportsで (2.7.10) をインストールしてあります。両バージョンとも、正常に動作します。

デフォルトのバージョンがPython (2.7.6) なのですが、2.7.10を優先的に使用したいと考えています。
2.7.10に変更する方法をご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

デフォルトのバージョンというのが、以下のようにターミナル等でpythonと打った時に使用される物のバージョンということであれば、PATHの指定でMacPortsでインストールしたpythonが置かれている`/opt/local/bin`を、Mac OSのデフォルトのpythonが置かれている`/usr/bin`よりで前方に指定すれば良いと思います。

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

具体的には`.bash_profile`とかに以下のように書いておくと良いと思います。

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: ＠tomute`export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH`で変更できるのですが、PCをシャットダウンすると元に戻ってしまします。シャットダウンやログアウトして再度使用する時にも、変わらないようにする方法はあるでしょうか。

Comment: ログインユーザのホームディレクトリ配下にある.bash_profileに'export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH'と書いておけば、PCをシャットダウンしても元に戻るという事は無いと思いますが、それでもダメですか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。無事解決しました。

Comment: そうですか。問題が解決できて何よりです。